# Should I need to use many or single API key for a flutter app?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, api-key

If I have an API as my back-end and flutter mobile application as my front end. To ensure that every request was made from the app I'm using a API key.

My question is that I have a single API key should I need to serve different API key for the users or else, A single API Key is enough for making requests?

Answer (score 1):

Yes single API key is enough to make many request, just make sure that the API key doesn't st expire .

you can save the API key as static variable in a class

```
Class ApiKey{
static String apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
}
```

and use it anywhere

```
print(ApiKey.apiKey);
```